# Returning Multiple Entries With WHERE subseach

Tags: mysql

I'm facing the following problem:
I have a table (new_form) that lists units that should answer a formulary. The information about those units are in another table (units), including the code of city (city_code) where they are. I want to find the information in the first table (new_form) about all the units that are there and are located in an specific city (8383).

```
SELECT * FROM `new_form`
WHERE `unit_number`=(
    SELECT `unit_number`
    FROM `units`
    WHERE `city_code`=8383
)
```

The way it is now, I get this error:

```
#1242 - Subconsulta retorna mais que 1 registro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`IN`**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `new_form`
WHERE `unit_number` in (
    SELECT `unit_number`
    FROM `units`
    WHERE `city_code`=8383
)
```

Alternately, you could use a **`JOIN`**:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM `new_form` f
INNER JOIN `units` u on f.`unit_number` = u.`unit_number`
WHERE u.`city_code`=8383
```

Comment: And what about the oposite way? How do I get the 'city_name' and 'city_code' from all entries in the table 'cities' that have units in the 'new_form' table?